# Did early nineteenth century commoners know their royalty?

Tags: europe, 19th-century

I'm wondering if European commoners in the early nineteenth century knew who their royalty was.  I'm sure not all of them would have recognized them face to face because there may have been little interaction, but would, say, a teenage girl (a commoner) know the name of the monarch running her country?

Comment: Considering the laws / governance / celebrations / festivals / toasts that would have been regularly held in the monarch's name, not to mention gossips, the *average* commoner should know who the sovereign is.

Comment: Of course they knew, very well even in middle ages, not to say nineteenth century when there were a lot of periodic newspapers, wall newspapers, books and other media.

Comment: Apart from the newspapers mentioned by Anixx (which were still not very popular at the beginning of the XIX), remember that usually, there were no Government officials but monarchy officials. Thus, any act by those officials would have been "in the name of King (or Queen) X", and the formula would have been repeated *ad nauseam*.

Comment: Plus, monarchs usually appeared on coins.

Comment: I am sure the British new. Type "British 1800 penny coin" on Google. Postage stamps were introduced in 1840. But surely all common people have seen penny coins.

Comment: I kind of assumed he was talking about the high middle ages, instead. _Of course_ they knew that in 1800…

Comment: In Britain at least the Sunday church service (which was pretty much universally attended in the early 19th century) there is a prayer for the king/queen, who is mentioned by name in the prayer.

Comment: I assumed as much.  I recently read a historical romance that takes place in the early nineteenth century and the main character has no clue who the ruler of her country is or anything about him and I found it really hard to believe that could be possible, but I wanted to find out for sure.  Obviously, the author didn't do any research on this matter!  Thanks for the answers, guys!

Comment: Of course. How can you make fun of them, if you don't know who they are?

Comment: This question really has no answer. Who knows what the _commoners_ did or did not _know_. I'm an obtuse person. Shit happens at work all the time that I don't know about until way after the fact, because I not only don't gossip, I don't spend time in idle chat. I'm simply not interested. That being said, I am 100% positive I would know who the President was, even if we didn't see his face every day. But does that mean that every young girl (or boy) would? of course not. But... how can we know for sure?

Comment: @Tacy Stine this depends on the age, it is possible to assume that a child or a teenager of say 14, especially a girl may not be interested in politics and not know who the head of state is or may confuse the things badly.

Comment: @Tacy Stine Sounds like Harlequin Historicals strikes again. Many of their "historical" romances would be better set on soft scifi worlds. They are researched by having seen some movies over the years and not thinking too critically about their "clever" way to have the heroine meet the prince but never recognize him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is very clearly yes. Images of European monarchs were commonly reproduced on coinage, in newspapers, and in public art. Not only sovereigns but princes and minor royalty were also usually recognizable to common people. Also, most monarchs in 19th C. Europe were (or hoped to be) considered military leaders. If you're talking about "early 19th C. Europe," you're talking about the age of Napoleon. These wars were closely followed in every European country. Napoleon wasn't "real" royalty, but he was instantly recognizable and very well-known to everyone on the continent. His opponents on the field of battle, including the Prussian, Austrian and English monarchs, were feted during and after the wars to the point that their faces and names would have been widely known. Princes of smaller German states (e.g., Hesse, Mecklenburg-Schwerin, Reuss) had coins and medals minted with their likenesses on them. Numerous newspapers printed comics and illustrations. Deaths and coronations were huge, popular events, so transitions of power were well documented and known to the subjects of 19th C. European states. These people were famous. Even Queens were well known. Louise of Prussia (lived 1776-1810) had a virtual personality cult built around her, especially after her death. After the Congress of Vienna, even a teenage girl from Dresden could have told you that her shamed king was named Frederick Augustus, and could probably have picked him out of a lineup.

Comment: What would be that "public art" that you mention? Artists did work for the aristocracy and the rich, and those did use the art works to decorate their palaces and mansions, not to create publicly accessible museums. I agree that the people would know their King or Queen's name, but (unless they are so good at recognizing people that they could recognize faces based in the coins portraits) they would have trouble recognizing them physically.

Comment: By public art I mean primarily statues. Wilhelm I of Prussia had 63 equestrian statues, 231 standing statues, 5 seated statues and 126 busts, many or most on public display. Granted he was not from the "early" 19th C., but numbers for him were readily available. Also many paintings of sovereigns were on public display. David's Napoleons come to mind.

Answer (score -4):

Not likely.  The Church was the principal source if "news" then. They would have known about the actions of the priests, bishops, cardinals and the Pope... but rarely was there ant goid reason to involve illiterate commoners in secular government. What would have been the point?

Comment: In early nineteenth century? How about conscripting them to go fight in the Napoleonic wars? Have them take part in some revolution or other, extract taxes from them, get their kids to take the mandatory primary education?

Comment: News about cardinals? Well, I am sure news about cardinals and bishops never were as important as those about the government even at the height of the Church influence in the Middle Ages. Unless said cardinals were also the ministers at the same time, like Mazarin or Richelieu.

Comment: This is after The Enlightenment. Which is after the Protestant movements. Which means in many places the Lutheran peasants couldn't tell you the name of the Pope, let alone any cardinal.